# FLAG 'Y' to first matched condition in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, case

Table A :

```
  ID      AMOUNT   Order
 -------------------------
  1       100       1
  1       300       2
  1       320       3
  2       100       1
  2       200       2
  2       423       3
  2       613       4
  3       112       1
  3       218       2
  3       290       3
  3       480       4
```

Expected Output :
Table A :

```
  ID      AMOUNT   Order  Flag
 ------------------------------
  1       100       1
  1       300       2
  1       320       3
  2       100       1
  2       200       2
  2       423       3      Y
  2       613       4
  3       112       1
  3       218       2
  3       290       3      
  3       480       4      Y
```

I have a Table A which have duplicate IDs with multiple amount in some order.
I want to display Flag Y to the first row that match the given condition. Condition is : Flag Y to the 1st row which have Amount greater or equal to 400 and Order greater or equal to 3.

The query I tried is :

```
Select * , case when (Order >= 3 and Amount >=400) then 'Y' else '' end as FLAG from TableA
```

But this query flagged all the rows that match the condition but I need to Flag only the first row that match this condition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select t1.*, case when t2.id is not null then 'Y' else '' end as FLAG
  from myTable t1
  left join (
select id, min([Order]) minOrder
  from myTable
  where ( [Order] >= 3 and Amount >= 400)
  group by id) t2 on t1.id = t2.id and t1.[Order] = t2.[minOrder];
```

[DBFiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/v1jhbvnB)

Answer (score 1):

you can check for the existence of another column prior of the actual

```
Select * 
  , case when ([Order] >= 3 and Amount >=400
  AND  NOT EXISTS( SELECT 1 FROM TableA WHERE ID = t.ID AND [Order] < t.[Order] AND [Order] >= 3 and Amount >=400)) then 'Y' else '' end as FLAG 
  
  from TableA t
```

| ID | AMOUNT | Order | FLAG |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 100 | 1 |  |
| 1 | 300 | 2 |  |
| 1 | 320 | 3 |  |
| 2 | 100 | 1 |  |
| 2 | 200 | 2 |  |
| 2 | 423 | 3 | Y |
| 2 | 613 | 4 |  |
| 3 | 112 | 1 |  |
| 3 | 218 | 2 |  |
| 3 | 290 | 3 |  |
| 3 | 480 | 4 | Y |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/PjDvuTmO)

Answer (score 1):

We can use exists logic here:

```sql
SELECT ID, AMOUNT, [Order],
       CASE WHEN [Order] >= 3 AND AMOUNT > 400 AND
            NOT EXISTS (
                SELECT 1
                FROM TableA t2
                WHERE t2.ID = t1.ID AND
                      t2.[Order] < t1.[Order] AND
                      t2.AMOUNT > 400
            )
            THEN 'Y' END AS Flag
FROM TableA t1
ORDER BY ID, [Order];
```